# Perspectives using different fact tables, same dimensions

Tags: ssas, cube, bids, perspective

My client has asked me to create a different perspective for an existing cube that shows only a subset of the fact table. I'm not sure if this is even possible though. I was hoping that I can bring in the same fact table again, filter it, and join it to all of the existing dimensions, but it doesn't look like I can select which fact table to use in the Perspectives tab.

Does anyone have other solutions to this problem? Or is it not possible to do at all? As a last resort I will create a new cube, but it is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that you need to create another Measures group with the filtered fact table set up the Dimension Usage the same way as the original perspective, and then create a new Perspective from that, filtering out the original measure group.